# Why am I getting different length and travel time from OSMnx or networkx when comparing it with Google Maps?

Tags: networkx, data-analysis, openstreetmap, shortest-path, osmnx

I'm new working with OSM data, OSMnx and networkx libraries, so if there's a better way to accomplish on getting shortest path from A to B locations, I'll appreciate any advice.

I'm trying to get shortest path from A to B. I successfully get the path, but length and time travel are very different comparing them with what Google Maps returns.
1. Why path length and travel time are very different from Google Maps / Bing Maps?
2. How can I improve accuracy?

Addresses used:
3115 W Bancroft St, Toledo, OH 43606
6721 Whiteford Center Rd, Lambertville, MI 48144

```
OSMnx length = 9135 mts, travel time = 8.3 min.
Google Maps length = 9334.2 mts, travel time = 12 min.
BingMaps length = 9334.2 mts, travel time = 13 min.
Difference in distance is 199.2 mts and aprox ~ 5 min
```

```py
import sys
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
from shapely.geometry import box, Point
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

def geocode(address):
    """Geocode an address using OSMnx."""
    try:
        x, y = ox.geocode(address)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {str(e)}')
        return None, None
    return x, y

def boundary_constructor(orig_x, orig_y, dest_x, dest_y):
    """Create a bounding box around two points."""
    boundary_box = Point(orig_y, orig_x).buffer(0.001).union(Point(dest_y, dest_x).buffer(0.001)).bounds
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = boundary_box
    bbox = box(*[minx, miny, maxx, maxy])
    return bbox

def getting_osm(bbox, network_type, truncate_edges):
    """Retrieve OSM data (roads, edges, nodes) for a given bounding box and network type."""
    G = ox.graph_from_polygon(bbox, retain_all=False, network_type=network_type, truncate_by_edge=truncate_edges)
    G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
    G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)
    roads = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True)
    return G, roads

def find_closest_node(G, lat, lng, distance):
    """Find the closest node in a graph to a given latitude and longitude."""
    node_id, dist_to_loc = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, X=lat, Y=lng, return_dist=distance)
    return node_id, dist_to_loc

def shortest_path(G, orig_node_id, dest_node_id, weight):
    """Find the shortest path between two nodes in a graph."""
    try:
        route = ox.shortest_path(G, orig_node_id, dest_node_id, weight=weight)
    except nx.NetworkXNoPath as e:
        print(f"No path found between {orig_node_id} and {dest_node_id}")
        print(e)
    return route

def find_length_and_time(G, travel_length, travel_time):
    try:
        route_length = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, travel_length, "length")["length"]))
        route_time = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, travel_time, "travel_time")["travel_time"]))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
    return route_length, route_time
    

def route_plotting(G, travel_length, travel_time):
    """Plot the shortest path between two addresses."""
    if travel_length and travel_time:
        fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(
            G,
            routes=[travel_length, travel_time],
            route_colors=["r", "y"],
            route_linewidth=6,
            node_size=0
        )
    elif travel_length:
        ox.plot_route_folium(G, travel_length, popup_attribute='length')
    elif travel_time:
        ox.plot_route_folium(G, travel_time, popup_attribute='travel_time')

def main():
    # User address input
    origin_address = str(input('Enter the origin address: '))
    destination_address = str(input('Enter the destination adddress: '))
    # Geocode addresses
    orig_x, orig_y = geocode(origin_address)
    dest_x, dest_y = geocode(destination_address)
    # Check if geocoding was successful
    if not all([orig_x, orig_y, dest_x, dest_y]):
        print("Unable to geocode one or both addresses. Exiting...")
        sys.exit()
    # Create bounding box
    bbox = boundary_constructor(orig_x, orig_y, dest_x, dest_y) 
    # Retrieve OSM data
    G, roads = getting_osm(bbox, network_type='drive', truncate_edges='True')
    # Find closest node
    orig_node_id, dist_to_orig = find_closest_node(G, orig_y, orig_x, True)
    dest_node_id, dist_to_dest = find_closest_node(G, dest_y, dest_x, True)
    # find shortest path
    travel_length = shortest_path(G, orig_node_id, dest_node_id, weight='length')
    travel_time = shortest_path(G, orig_node_id, dest_node_id, weight='travel_time')
    # find route length and route time
    route_length, route_time = find_length_and_time(G, travel_length, travel_time)
    if route_length and route_time:
        print(f"Shortest travel length:{route_length: .2f} meters and takes {(route_time/60)} minutes") 
    elif route_length:
        print(f"Shortest travel length: {route_length: .2f}. No travel time found")
    elif route_time:
        print(f"Shortest travel time: {(route_time/60)}. No travel length found")
    # plot routes
    route_plotting(G, travel_length, travel_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How big differences are they? I'd guess there are OSM journey planning tools online: does yours match their routes and times? If you do want to compare Google and Bing I'd double check that your routes match the ones they generate, and I'd break down your journeys into simple sections and get individual length and times for each section. It might also be worth comparing walking times, since Google and Bing will take account of expected traffic for driving journeys at the specific time of day which your model won't.

Comment: The difference is aprox 200 meters and 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the path length and travel time are so different from Google Maps and Bing Maps?

Broadly, it's some combination of those mapping providers having better data and better algorithms.

Starting with data, most streets in open street maps do not have the maximum legal speed annotated. For any of these streets, OSMnx attempts to guess the max speed by looking at the [highway type](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway), and looking at roads of the same highway type which do have maxspeed annotations. ([Source](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/cabdbb246dc14095f5d8e8b8ead38f9649dae2c7/osmnx/speed.py#L95).) The assumption is that if the average residential street in a city has a max speed of 20 mph, then a residential street with no known speed limit probably has a max speed of 20 mph. Of course, this assumption is not always true, and your route plan will be better quality if it knows the actual speed.

To improve this, you can provide the `hwy_speeds` argument to `add_edge_speeds()`, if you know what speed limits unposted streets have in your jurisdiction.

This gets into the next problem, which is that people don't always drive the speed limit. Sometimes they drive faster, or sometimes there's traffic and they have to slow down. This is hard to solve without some data source with traffic info.

Another issue is that OSMnx assumes that all intersections take zero seconds to cross. The algorithm that OSMnx uses to find the fastest route does not allow intersections (or nodes) to have any travel time. Even if that weren't a problem, one would need to figure out how long an intersection takes to cross. (Some questions you'd need to think about to solve this: does this intersection have a stoplight? Is this a right or left turn? Do you have right-of-way?)

In summary, there are four factors which can cause the travel time to differ:

- Imputing a street with an unknown speed with the average speed for that category
- Drivers who speed
- Traffic
- Assumption that intersections take no time

Of these four factors, two of them can cause an underestimate of travel time. One of them can cause an overestimate. One of them can affect your estimate in either direction. In my experience, OSMnx usually underestimates travel time.

Comment: Note that enriched route solving (including turn time penalties and stop sign/traffic signal penalties) is currently planned for OSMnx v2.0.

Comment: @gboeing Very nice! I'll be watching for that - accurate travel times is very interesting for a project I'm working on.

Comment: that's awesome! @gboeing , can't wait.